# calling scrollto after history.push in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using history.push for routing (using react-router-dom 5.3.4)

Most of the links on my menu are just scrollTo
One of the links goes to /about

when i use one of the scrollTo links from the /about page,
i call

```
history.push("/");
window.scrollTo({top: 500px, behaviour: 'smooth'})
```

the push works, but the scrollto doesnt do anytting.

I have tried several things including timeouts and listening to the path change before calling, but i still cant get it to do the scrollTo after the push.

```
  //   // This will unlisten to the history changes after it's done
  //   const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  //     if (location.pathname === "/" && action === "PUSH") {
  //       // console.log("We have returned home");
  //       // console.log(target);
  //         target();
  //         unlisten(); // remove the listener once we're done
  //     }
  // });

  history.push("/");
  target();
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   console.log('added timeout');
    //   // target();
    //   // window.scrollTo(1000,0);
    //   // window.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    //   // document.getElementById("issue").scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    // }, 300);
```

any suggestions?

`target()`
Is a function that gets called which is assigned from an array.

```
const links = [
  { type: 'internal', target: useScrollToPurpose(), label: 'PURPOSE' },
  { type: 'internal', target: useScrollToIssue(), label: 'ISSUE' },
  { type: 'internal', target: useScrollToAssess(), label: 'ASSESS' },
  { type: 'internal', target: useScrollToActNow(), label: 'ACT NOW' },
  { type: 'about', target: '/about', label: 'MORE ABOUT THE PROGRAM' }
];
```

each of those use functions call this with a different decimal to get different points on the main page.

```
  const scrollToProgress = (progress) => {
    const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const scrollY = progress * (documentHeight - windowHeight);
    setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo({
      top: scrollY,
      behavior: "smooth"
    }), 0);
  };
```

THey are used as a menu to jump to specific points on the main page

Comment: Do you want *always* to `windows.scrollTo({top: 500px, behaviour: 'smooth'})` when navigating to the `"/"` route, or only when navigating *from* certain routes or specifically when a specific link/button is used? Can you [edit] to clarify the use case in a bit more detail, what you are trying to accomplish overall?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo `windows.scrollTo` instead of `window.scrollTo`.

Attempting to run `window.scrollTo()` immediately after `history.push("/")` could potentially target the current page rather than the new one because `history.push()` doesn’t instantly navigate to a new page. Instead, it triggers a navigation that occurs “soon after” the method call.

In SPAs like react here, when navigation occurs, the page doesn’t reload; rather, components are swapped in and out, which may not inherently trigger a scroll change.

You can use an useEffect to deliver scrollTop in `/` page.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function HomePage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({top: 500, behavior: 'smooth'});
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div>
      Welcome to the Home Page
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: the scrollTo is used as navigation.
the exact scroll positions are needed as it runs animation.